# Trouble Building a Simpletest Suite From Working Unit Test Cases

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, simpletest

I've started using unit testing for my PHP programs, and figured Simpletest was as good a place to dive in as any other.  I added the Simpletest files to my testing server, and ran the following tests on my custom PDO classes:

```
<?php
require_once('../simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once('../includes/inc_sql.php');

class TestOfSQL extends UnitTestCase{
    function testRead(){
        ...
    }

    function testWriteAndDelete(){
        ...
    }
}
?>
```

That all works out smashingly.  I try to build a test suite involving (so far) just that testing file, as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('../simpletest/autorun.php');

class AllTests extends TestSuite {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addFile('inc_sql_test.php');
    }
}
```

This crashes and burns, and I get the following readout:

```
Warning: include_once(inc_sql_test.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\historicMuncie\simpletest\test_case.php on line 382

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'inc_sql_test.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\historicMuncie\simpletest\test_case.php on line 382

Warning: file_get_contents(inc_sql_test.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\historicMuncie\simpletest\test_case.php on line 418
all_tests.php
Fail: AllTests -> inc_sql_test.php -> Bad TestSuite [inc_sql_test.php] with error [No runnable test cases in [inc_sql_test.php]]
0/0 test cases complete: 0 passes, 1 fails and 0 exceptions.
```

I've played around with include paths, web root vs. server root notation - anything that came to mind, but nothing is allowing that test suite to run properly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always cringe when I see relative paths in PHP scripts. It's much easier to implement and maintain when using "semi-absolute" paths based on a common root. Try:

```
$this->addFile( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc_sql_test.php' );
```

Comment: That did it!  A follow-up, though.  I usually don't have a problem with relative PHP paths, and this makes things awkward when transitioning to a production server, as the files won't be the same number of levels from the document root.  Is there a simple workaround, or should I go through and do a find/replace on all includes before a push to production?

Comment: Ideally, your development environment should be as close to that of production as possible. If this isn't possible, consider setting up a "staging" or "pre-production test" system for finalizing and verifying before going to production. That way you have less chance of overlooking something and taking down the site. Alternatively, create a "push" script that does any translations. You don't want to end up doing every deployment by hand because you will inevitably miss something.

Comment: One other option is to define a constant in your configuration include file that specifies the root path, and then use that throughout the application. Then, you can just change the configuration file for production.

Comment: That seems like the cleanest solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$this->addFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc_sql_test.php');
```

Regards!